# var error = new Error(message); Why am I getting this message in the terminal?

Tags: solidity, nodes, router, smartcontracts, abi

Everything works effectively until I add the `const amountOut` to the file.

[Code with Error & location of function that breaks code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WITM0.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing 2 parameters into a function that is expecting 3. The second parameter is one value because you have it as an array in brackets - [AddressFrom, AddressTo].

You will need to either modify how you are passing in the parameters to the getAmountsOut function or modify the getAmountsOut function to accept 2 parameters, with one being an array.

Comment: "You will need to either modify how you are passing in the parameters to the 'getAmountsOut' function or modify the 'getAmountsOut' function to accept 2 parameters, with one being an array." <--- The BNB 'AddressRouter' function itself contains only 2 input parameters on bscscan (0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E), one of them being the array... I've now reached an impasse as to the modification of the function because it already reflects the 2 input parameters of the BNB contract. If you can give me any suggestions, it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: @W3C0d3 can you please attach the code to the getAmountsOut function?

Comment: The clues you left for me led me to figuring out my error. I had 'getAmountsOut' function in my ABI file with 3 parameters instead of 2. This was my first time encountering an issue like this, but now I have a MUCH better understanding of the interaction between files in a contract, as well as the intricacies of interactions between contracts